# Select record based on specific date in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select a record from specified date

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$this->db->get_where('tablename', array('postid' => $dailystat['postid'], 'timestamp >=' => $yesterday));
```

But i am not getting any record even if there are entries in table. I also want to make sure that query select the only record which was created on specified date.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: What is` timestamp` column format in DB? 146765565 or  Y-m-d ?

Comment: already tried but it's not working for me..

Comment: @m-eskandari its Y-m-d which is why i used Y-m-d for yesterday date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$this->db->get_where('tablename', array('postid' => $dailystat['postid'], 'timestamp >=' => $yesterday, 'timestamp <' => date('Y-m-d')));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you share your table schema and sample data, I can give you correct answer. Still I can guess you are compairing date string with timestamp.
The code `$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));` will return `$yesterday` value as `'2017-04-10'`. But actually in your database you are compairing with timestamp field, which hold the timestamp in numeric value.

You can use php strtotime function to convert any date to respective time stamp. `strtotime($yesterday).`

Correct Code will be :

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$this->db->get_where('tablename', array('postid' => $dailystat['postid'], 'timestamp >=' => strtotime($yesterday)));
```

*Again please make sure, your database field timestamp is storing only date in form of timestamp.*

***Another solution is, you can use mysql date compare functions.***